# setTimeout Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, settimeout

I have the following javascript in MSIE:

```
setTimeout(myFunction, 1000, param );
```

this seems to work in all browsers except internet explorer. the param just doesnt get forwarded to the function. looking at the debugger, it is undefined.

Comment: Just use an anonymous function...

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`param` in Internet explorer specifies whether the code in `myFunction` is JScript, JavaScript or VBscript <sup>See also: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa741500(v=vs.85).aspx)</sup>. It does not behave like other browsers.

The following will work:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    myFunction(param);
}, 1000);
```

The previous line does not exactly mimic `setTimeout` in Firefox etc. To pass a variable, unaffected by a later update to the `param` variable, use:

```
setTimeout( (function(param) {
    return function() {
        myFunction(param);
    };
})(param) , 1000);
```

Comment: @clamp The `param` at the bottom is the original `param` variable. `param` at the top is a local variable for the self-invoking function. `param` at the middle resolves to `param` at the top.

Comment: thank you! everything seems to work now in all browsers, just some post processing tools like jshint and google closure compiler complain that this is invalid syntax. but i guess, this should be another question then.

Comment: I don't get any warnings/errors with the snippet alone in the [Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) or [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/).

Comment: i have to mention that the parameter is an array like this: [a,b]

Comment: @clamp That's still not sufficient. If you really want to solve this (interesting?) problem, don't hesitate to post a new question, including the relevant code to demonstrate your case.

Answer (score 4):

Internet Explorer does not allow you to pass parameters like that. You'll have to do it explicitly from the callback function:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    myFunction(param);
}, 1000);
```

---

Quote from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout):

> Note that passing additional parameters to the function in the first syntax does not work in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at http://www.makemineatriple.com/2007/10/passing-parameters-to-a-function-called-with-settimeout

Looks like you'll need something like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){ myFunction(param) }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

That isn't a parameter. Apparently, that last argument is denoting the scripting language.

Use an anonymous function instead:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  myFunction(param);
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an anonymous function:

```
setTimeout(function() { myFunction(param) }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    myFunction(param);
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use closure:

```
setTimeout(function(){myFunction(param)}, 1000);
```