# IE parameters get undefined when using them in setTimeout

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, settimeout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [setTimeout Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568248/settimeout-internet-explorer)

Am I missing something here or is there a problem in Internet Explorer when passing function parameters to a [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) calling the same function?

This will run forever in Internet Explorer:

```
function myFunction(myParam, tries){
  if (typeof tries == "undefined"){
    tries = 0;
  }
  tries++;
  if (tries < 2){
    setTimeout(myFunction, 50, myParam, tries);
  }
}
myFunction("something");
```

Is there a way to work around that problem?

http://fiddle.jshell.net/rH3gx/

Comment: This took me an hour or two to figure out why my outer scope variable was `undefined`. Internet Explorer is the worst!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The explanation and solution are [in the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) :

> If you need to pass an argument to your callback function, but need it
>   to work in Internet Explorer, which doesn't support sending additional
>   parameters (neither with setTimeout() or setInterval()) you can
>   include this IE-specific compatibility code which will enable the
>   HTML5 standard parameters passage functionality in that browser for
>   both timers just by inserting it at the beginning of your scripts.

```
if (document.all && !window.setTimeout.isPolyfill) {
  var __nativeST__ = window.setTimeout;
  window.setTimeout = function (vCallback, nDelay /*, argumentToPass1, argumentToPass2, etc. */) {
    var aArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
    return __nativeST__(vCallback instanceof Function ? function () {
      vCallback.apply(null, aArgs);
    } : vCallback, nDelay);
  };
  window.setTimeout.isPolyfill = true;
}

if (document.all && !window.setInterval.isPolyfill) {
  var __nativeSI__ = window.setInterval;
  window.setInterval = function (vCallback, nDelay /*, argumentToPass1, argumentToPass2, etc. */) {
    var aArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
    return __nativeSI__(vCallback instanceof Function ? function () {
      vCallback.apply(null, aArgs);
    } : vCallback, nDelay);
  };
  window.setInterval.isPolyfill = true;
}
```

Comment: setTimeout appears to work with parameters in IE10. However, I can't find anything documenting support for the functionality in IE10+. MSDN still indicates that it is unsupported: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ie/ms536753.aspx

Comment: @KevinBabcock The MDN is more precise than MSDN on this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 8):

http://fiddle.jshell.net/rH3gx/2/

You need to wrap the function in a function which requires no arguments:

```
function myFunction(myParam, tries){
  if (typeof tries == "undefined"){
    tries = 0;
  }
  tries++;
  if (tries < 2){
    setTimeout(function() {
         myFunction(myParam, tries);
    }, 50);

  }
}

myFunction("something");
```

Comment: This worked best for me

Comment: won't work if the arguments are changed during those 50ms

Comment: Worked for me in IE and Chome.  Thanks.

Comment: @denns the arguments can't change in this example

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimeout(function(){myFunction(myParam, tries);}, 50);
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/rH3gx/1/