# JavaScript setTimeout not work on IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, settimeout

Preloader work 3sec, and the show the site content. But in IE and on MackBook preloader work infinitely... How can i fix that?

```
<div id="page-preloader"><span class="spinner"></span></div>

<script>
var waiting = new Promise(function (resolve) {
    setTimeout(resolve, 3000);
});
waiting.then(function () {
        var $preloader = $('#page-preloader'),
            $spinner = $preloader.find('.spinner');
        $spinner.fadeOut();
        $preloader.delay(350).fadeOut('slow');
    });

      </script>
```

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=Promise

Comment: https://www.promisejs.org/

Answer (score -1):

IE set timeout does not work like other browsers.

`param` in Internet explorer specifies whether the code in myFunction is JScript, JavaScript or VBscript See also: MSDN. It does not behave like other browsers.

Following will work:

```
function myFunction(){
    var $preloader = $('#page-preloader'),
    $spinner = $preloader.find('.spinner');
    $spinner.fadeOut();
    $preloader.delay(350).fadeOut('slow');
});

setTimeout( (function(param) {
    return function() {
        myFunction(param);
    };
})(param) , 3000);
```

For more information check out:
[setTimeout Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568248/settimeout-internet-explorer)

Comment: I try, not work.                                                                                       var waiting = new Promise(function (resolve) {
    setTimeout(function() {
    myFunction(param);
}, 3000);
});
waiting.then(function () {
        var $preloader = $('#page-preloader'),
            $spinner = $preloader.find('.spinner');
        $spinner.fadeOut();
        $preloader.delay(350).fadeOut('slow');
    });