# apply not working on window.setTimeout IE7 and IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, settimeout, apply

When I try to execute the following code, it throws an error in IE7 and 8.

```
var savedWindowSetTimeout = window.setTimeout;
savedWindowSetTimeout.call(window, function(){}, 0)
```

The error thrown is

```
object doesn't support property or method apply
```

Is there any workaround for this in IE7 and IE8, where I can use call or apply on **window.setTimeout**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setTimeout internet explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568248/settimeout-internet-explorer)

Comment: I don't think so. This problem talks about 'apply' function not available on window.setTimeout in IE. I tried to search StackOverflow for this, but didn't find any solution

Comment: current browser support question: Neither ie7 nor ie8 are officially supported anymore. They're not just "old browsers", as of January 2016 Microsoft permanently and irrevocably killed them off as supported browsers of any kind, because (and this is the important part) no operating system that uses those browsers is supported by Microsoft anymore. So part of the counter-question here is "why are you trying to solve a problem for products that no longer exist"?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans That depends on the market. If you check browser stats for some of the most important websites all over south america, still 10 or 15% are old Internet Explorer versions. And honestly, sometimes clients doesn’t mind if the browser is no longer supported by its manufacturer, they only want better user experience. I agree than IE versions older than 10 shouldn’t be any project browser targets, but sometimes those are the project specs and you must stick to those specs.

Comment: Hence the question. If skindal93 has a good reason to argue they really need this, then I'm sure someone can come in and help them out, but if not, they might not have realised they are asking about dead technology, akin to asking "how do I use a webfont in IE4". There is an answer, but it's irrelevant in 2018. That might, or might not, be the case here.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Yeah. We have a reason to support IE7 and IE8 because of the reason mentioned by muecas above. People are still using those browsers, and we have to figure out things separately most of the time for old IE browsers.

Comment: Usually for older browser the strategy is "don't match what you're doing in modern browsers", so: what are you trying to _do_ here that requires using `setTimeout` in combination with `apply` (mostly asking to avoid an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378))? Why would you not just use the normal setTimeout pattern (with `.bind` if you really need to preserve execution context, but it looks like your context is `window`, which is *always* available, just reference that in your function, no need for bind there).

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to the problem. You can pollyfill window.setTimeout in such a way that it works on older IE browsers too. The polyfill looks like this

```
var __nativeST__ = window.setTimeout;

window.setTimeout = function (vCallback, nDelay /*, argumentToPass1, argumentToPass2, etc. */) {
  var oThis = this, 
      aArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
  return __nativeST__(vCallback instanceof Function ? function () {
    vCallback.apply(oThis, aArgs);
  } : vCallback, nDelay);
};
```

Found this polyfill on MDN website https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

Comment: This looks fairly ridiculous compared to just calling `setTimeout( function() { window.doTheThingYouNeed(); }, ...)` so before you do a deep dive into weird hacks for older IE, let's back up and figure out what you're trying to do, instead of how to make what you think was the solution work.